# Is this a type of constructor?

Tags: c++, function, class, constructor

I was looking through a c++ book I have, and I found this example of code

```
class CDistance
{
private:
    int feet, inches;
public:
    CDistance();
    CDistance(int, int);
    ~CDistance();
    void setDist();
    void printDist() const;
    CDistance add(const CDistance&) const;
};
```

I understand Constructors and overloading and that kind of thing, but what about this prototype on the bottom that's of the class type. The book, strangely enough, didn't give any information on it, just the diagram. But I was just wondering, what does it mean that the function type is of the class. I'm pretty sure I understand the parameter, as it seems to be a constant reference to an object of that class type. But why/how could you declare a function like that, does it mean that it returns the class? Lol, I'm new to programming, and if someone could help me understand this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It is simply a function which takes a const reference to a CDistance and returns a CDistance.

Comment: Constructors are named the same as the class/structure, and does not have any return values.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I think "return type" is the more appropriate terminology. Return *values* are things that come from function call expressions, and constructors aren't functions.

Comment: @KerrekSB Really? They are described in section 12, "Special member functions", e.g. "The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are *special member functions*." And there are numerous other mentions of the word "function" throughout.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Sure, but you can't form function call expressions with constructors, and you can't form function pointers. So you have to be careful about what you mean by "function".

Answer (score 4):

You call a function a constructor only if it has the name of the class. The function of type `CDistance` means that the function returns an object of the class. So it is not a constructor

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are different from normal member functions in certain ways:

- they don't have a return type
- their name is the same as the class name
- they cannot be const qualified

This makes the function `CDistance::add` not a constructor, because it fails on all 3.

Comment: * they are not prefixed by tildes (~)

Comment: Technically, a constructor doesn't have a name at all.  This is mere pedantry in this case however.

Comment: @fxam Not really. A constructor is simply defined as an optional sequence of `function-specifier` (where some are disallowed) followed by the class name followed by a parameter list. This is nearly the same way a destructor is specified, but you don't need to mention the tilde to say what a constructor is. But that is technical pedantry as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

did you mean : `CDistance add(const CDistance&) const;`?

this is the detail :

1. the purpose of `const` in the parameter is to make sure that the original object must not be changed via its reference...
   the `const` after parameter is to ensure that the the method must not change anything in its body..
2. that function return object of `CDistance`, so after the execution you can either use a new object to get it, as Example :

`CDistance tempObj = theObj.add (param_obj);`

hope that help... :D

Answer (score 0):

It is useful:

CDistance D1 = CDistance();

CDistance D2 = CDistance();

CDistance D3 = CDistance();

D3.add( D2.add(D1) );